# InDesign export PDF: Visible non-printable layers

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, interactive

I try to export a document as interactive PDF with non-printing layers but they don't appear in the exported file (they are visible but non-printing). The file has to be interactive due to buttons etc.

Is there a way to achieve this?